# why ModalBottomSheet in jetpack compose is throwing error?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, material-design, jetpack

I have modalbottomsheet implementation in a composable, but it's causing crash in my app due to the following erorr, please help for this below error I am not able to find it's solution, I using compose version, I am using **accompanist Permission library** also.

Compose Dependencies Versions:

> ```
> const val ACTIVITY_COMPOSE = "1.7.2"
> const val CONSTRAINT_LAYOUT = "1.0.1"
> const val composeVersion = "1.3.0"
> const val navVersion = "2.7.2"
> const val VIEWMODEL_COMPOSE = "2.6.1"
> const val VIEWMODEL_KTX = "2.4.0"
> const val MATERIAL_M3 = "1.2.0-alpha05"
> const val permissionVersion = "0.33.2-alpha"
> ```

Exception thrown :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.cityof.glendale, PID: 13435
> **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotFloatStateKt;**
> at androidx.compose.material3.SwipeableV2State.(SwipeableV2.kt:252)
> at androidx.compose.material3.SheetState.(SheetDefaults.kt:276)
> at androidx.compose.material3.SheetDefaultsKt.SheetState(SheetDefaults.kt:74)
> at androidx.compose.material3.SheetDefaultsKt$rememberSheetState$2$1.invoke(SheetDefaults.kt:497)
> at androidx.compose.material3.SheetDefaultsKt$rememberSheetState$2$1.invoke(SheetDefaults.kt:496)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.RememberSaveableKt.rememberSaveable(RememberSaveable.kt:89)
> at androidx.compose.material3.SheetDefaultsKt.rememberSheetState(SheetDefaults.kt:489)
> at androidx.compose.material3.ModalBottomSheet_androidKt.rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheet.android.kt:297)
> at com.cityof.glendale.screens.more.PhotoPickerKt.PhotoPickerSheet(PhotoPicker.kt:66)
> at com.cityof.glendale.screens.more.MoreScreenKt.ProfileComposable(MoreScreen.kt:265)
> at com.cityof.glendale.screens.more.MoreScreenKt$ProfileComposable$5.invoke(Unknown
> Source:14)
> at com.cityof.glendale.screens.more.MoreScreenKt$ProfileComposable$5.invoke(Unknown
> Source:10)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:192)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2531)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2800)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3281)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3232)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:932)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1143)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:124)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:580)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:548)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:41)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1035)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:845)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:775)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1022)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
> Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException:
> [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@82ac177,
> androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@a30d1e4,
> StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@115064d, AndroidUiDispatcher@a6d5502]
> 23:59:13.689  E  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't
> find class "androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotFloatStateKt" on path:
> DexPathList[[dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes5.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes12.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes13.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes14.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes15.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes16.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes6.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes7.dex",
> dex file
> "/data/data/com.cityof.glendale/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes10.dex",
> zip file
> "/data/app/~~AtY62ns5AQ6AVNAxo8dSdg==/com.cityof.glendale-CmpbLonsAMPwBprON9FZog==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~AtY62ns5AQ6AVNAxo8dSdg==/com.cityof.glendale-CmpbLonsAMPwBprON9FZog==/lib/x86_64,
> /data/app/~~AtY62ns5AQ6AVNAxo8dSdg==/com.cityof.glendale-CmpbLonsAMPwBprON9FZog==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64,
> /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
> at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
> ... 38 more

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code of the ModalBottomSheet that you currently have.